# why the onCreateOptionMenu() called after show fragment but does not add item to toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, android-toolbar

I'm developing an android application , this app has a bottom navigation with 4 items and 4 fragments.

this is important for me that each fragment has to save its state after switching between them with bottom navigation .

so i did a trick and add all fragments to fragmentTransaction and going to hide all of them and while bottom navigation item clicked i show one of them and hide the other one .

The problem is onCreateOptionMenu just work at the first fragment , and in the other fragments it is called but not change my toolbar ...

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.pure_search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.city_action);
    // region get selected city and state
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CityMap", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("name", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        menuItem.setTitle(restoredText);
    }
    // region get selected city and state
    menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChooseStateActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2000);
            return false;
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

and also i added this to onCreateView :

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

I'm glad to see your answers .

Comment: Share your fragment code here.

Comment: @Kabir i added code, let's check it out . thanks

Comment: I think fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu() code have no issue found,but try to put  setHasOptionsMenu() within the fragment's onCreate() method.And also check log for onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: @Kabir that really strange for me , the first fragment show the item in the toolbar but the others not !!

Comment: Have you check log onCreateOptionsMenu() from other fragment .Just check other onCreateOptionsMenu(0 method is called or not?

Comment: @Kabir I debugged the other onCreateOptionMenu() methods , they are called but does not add items to the toolbar, just the first one do the action !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197793/discussion-between-mohammad-matin-freydouni-zadeh-and-kabir).